# Inserting Sheet from another Workbook in Excel Add-in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying to copy a sheet from an existing Excel Workbook and paste it into the current workbook using an Excel Add-in. I am using the following code but it is throwing an exception:

```
private void insertSamplingWksht_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new    
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     Workbook templateWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(templatePath);
     Worksheet from = (templateWorkbook.Sheets[1] as Worksheet); // Get first sheet
     Worksheet to = (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet as Worksheet);
     from.Copy(to, Type.Missing); // Throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'No such interface supported'
 }
```

I also tried the following which did not work either.

```
private void insertSamplingWksht_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    string templatePath = @"path to file";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    var activeWkbName = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name;

    int beforeCount = xlApp.Workbooks.Count; // 1

    var templateWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(templatePath);
    var from = (templateWorkbook.Sheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet);

    int afterCount = xlApp.Workbooks.Count; // also 1

    xlApp.Workbooks[activeWkbName].Activate(); // COMException: 'Invalid index. 
    from.Copy(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Type.Missing);
}
```

Comment: I've just copy paste your provided code (second version) under a new button and it worked as expected. The `afterCount` is correctly saying `2` I'd suggest to create a new project add a Ribbon and copy paste code from here. It must work. Make sure that the `Workbooks.Open` really opens the file (must be visible) after that

Comment: I tried the updated code on a fresh install of Excel and it worked perfectly. I am looking into some reg keys that might have caused the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a strange Excel issue. We had disabled the Excel welcome page via a registry key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\General\DisableBootToOfficeStart. For some strange reason this stopped this code from working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            // no need to open another Excel instance
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            // get the name of the active workbook to be able to return back
            var activeWkbName = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name;

            // open the template workbook - which will become active then
            var templateWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(templatePath);
            var from = (templateWorkbook.Sheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet); 

            // active the original one
            xlApp.Workbooks[activeWkbName].Activate();
            from.Copy(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: the xlApp.Workbooks[activeWkbName].Activate() line throws COMException: 'Invalid index'.

Comment: Strange, try to change the problematic line with xlApp.Workbooks.Item[activeWkbName].Activate();  works fine here

Comment: It looks like the Workbooks.Open() method is closing the workbook that is currently open. Workbooks.Count is 1 before and after calling Open()

Comment: Can you share your full code? At least the method, is it VSTO add-in? `Open` certainly doesn't close existing workbook